# get max value of each entry from subquery | SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have SQL table with 3 columns - product, product version, and results(number).
I want to create a query that return the max result to each uniq version.

Simple data :

| product | version | results |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 1 | 50 |
| X | 1 | 51 |
| X | 1 | 53 |
| X | 2 | 60 |
| X | 2 | 62 |
| X | 3 | 70 |
| X | 4 | 80 |
| X | 4 | 80 |
| X | 4 | 80 |
| Y | 1 | 50 |
| Y | 2 | 60 |
| Y | 3 | 70 |
| Y | 4 | 80 |

In this table, the return value for product X version 1 will be 53, product X version 2 - 62, product X version 3 - 70 and so on.

how can i get this query ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch the rows which have the Max value for a column for each distinct value of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121387/fetch-the-rows-which-have-the-max-value-for-a-column-for-each-distinct-value-of)

Comment: (Clearly,) This is a faq. Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Answer (score -1):

[`Distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) can usually be the answer to "top one per group" type of problems: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/z7csr6dP)

```sql
select distinct on (product,version) * --specify groups in parentheses
from my_table
order by product,version,--initial `order by` columns need to match `distinct on`
         results desc; --this now dictates what ends up as the top row per group
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do it using the window function `row_number()` to sort data in descending order, then row with `rn = 1` will be the highest :

```
with cte as (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by product, Version order by Results desc) as rn
  from mytable
)
select product, Version, Results
from cte
where rn = 1;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/NUgM6VgN)